# How do I access a function variable from main()

Tags: c

I'm attempting to use this character compare function in main() while ignoring case sensitivity. Is there a way to call toupper(ch1) and toupper(ch2) from main so that if the -i (for case insensitivity) is raised I can reuse the code.

```
int CharacterCompare( FILE *file1, FILE *file2, char file1name[], char file2name[] )
{
   int ch1, ch2;
   int differ = 0;

   do
   {

    ch1 = fgetc( file1 );
      ch2 = fgetc( file2 );
      differ++;

      if ( feof( file1 ) && !feof( file2 ) )
      {  
         printf( "EOF on %s\n", file1name );
         return 1;         
      }
      else if ( feof( file2 ) && !feof( file1) )
      {
         printf( "EOF on %s\n", file2name );
         return 1;
      }

      if (ch1 != ch2)
      {
         printf( "files differ: char %d\n", differ );
         return 1;
      }     
   } 
   while( ( !feof( file1 ) ) && ( !feof( file2 ) ) && (ch1 == ch2) );

   printf( "files are equal\n" );

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whether case sensitivity is required should be passed as another argument then.

Comment: why not call it in function CharacterCompare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long answer (not tested, but you shoukld get the idea):

```
int Compare(char ch1, char ch2, int ignorecase)
{
  if (ignorecase)
  {
    ch1 = toupper(ch1) ;
    ch2 = toupper(ch2) ;
  }

  return ch1 == ch2 ;
}


int CharacterCompare( FILE *file1, FILE *file2, char file1name[], char file2name[],
                      int ignorecase )
{
   int ch1, ch2;
   int differ = 0;

   do
   {
    ch1 = fgetc( file1 );
      ch2 = fgetc( file2 );
      differ++;

      if ( feof( file1 ) && !feof( file2 ) )
      {  
         printf( "EOF on %s\n", file1name );
         return 1;         
      }
      else if ( feof( file2 ) && !feof( file1) )
      {
         printf( "EOF on %s\n", file2name );
         return 1;
      }

      if (Compare(ch1, ch2, ignorecase))
      {
         printf( "files differ: char %d\n", differ );
         return 1;
      }     
   } 
   while( ( !feof( file1 ) ) && ( !feof( file2 ) ) && (ch1 == ch2) );

   printf( "files are equal\n" );

   return 0;
}
```

And in main e.g something like :

```
ignorecase = argv[1] == "-i" ;
int different = CharacterCompare(f2, f2, name1, name2, ignorecase) ;
```

Comment: Got it! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The short (and only) answer is: No, you can't access variables declared locally in other functions.

Instead pass the case-insensitivity as an argument to the function.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you need to reuse code, wrap it in its own function.

In this case, why could just call `toupper` from `main`:

```
...

  if (toupper(ch1) != toupper(ch2))
  {
     printf( "files differ: char %d\n", differ );
     return 1;
  }
 ...
  while( ( !feof( file1 ) ) && ( !feof( file2 ) ) && (toupper(ch1) == toupper(ch2)) );
```

or wrap the case-insensitive comparison into a function:

```
int caseinvariantcomp(char c1, char c2) {
    return toupper(c1) - toupper(c2);
}

...

  if (caseinvariantcomp(ch1, ch2))
  {
     printf( "files differ: char %d\n", differ );
     return 1;
  }
 ...
  while( ( !feof( file1 ) ) && ( !feof( file2 ) ) && (!caseinvariantcomp(ch1, ch2)) );
```